# Downloading PDF from API using POST

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api

Im trying to POST a request with some header information and other parameters to my api and then have it return a PDF file.

I've got the API communication working fine however I've tried several methods of viewing the PDF and none really work 100%. 
The method below was found on stackoverflow and returns response data in PDF format however when it's converted to a blob to view it becomes blank.

```
[API]
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
ReturnInformationITEM rtn = GetPDFData(); //Comes back as Base64
response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(System.Convert.FromBase64String(rtn.Data));
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
return response;


[client]
var blob=new Blob([result], {type: 'application/pdf'});
var pom = document.getElementById("pdf" + $counter); 
pom.setAttribute('href',window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
pom.setAttribute('download',"Test.pdf");
pom.setAttribute('target','_blank');

'I did have a click event here but firefox ignores it so I have to pass the href back to the pom and manully click it'
```

If I alter the API to return base64 and have the client decode it before becoming a blob it will diaply the page but with an ugly blob URL and when saving in safari it doesnt recognise the 'download' attribute.

Does anyone know a method which can be used which will work cross browser and and allow for a filename to be prefilled? and if possible auto show the file upon returning the post data.

Thanks

Mark

Comment: The only true method I can think of is to create a file server sive and pass the link down, that was the href will point to a true file and act as it should.